# When server is booting high load?

Tags: boot

From CSF statistic my server load in 30 days is never higher than 3, I have 8 core cpu and 3 sites with 10 000 unique visits per day.
When I reboot my server, and I log in into console, when he is loading cpanel, httpd, mysql etc I check always TOP command and server load is increasing up to 10, then he start to decrease to normal about 0.60.
Why server load is high when server is booting?
This is not the issue, just the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when your server starts, all these daemons perform their initialization and health checks. MySQL for instance might check all its tables and apache needs to load and initialize all modules.

Comment: You are right!
Thanks!
MySQL is using CPU on boot I checked now.

Answer (score 0):

Load is the average number of waiting processes. When there is a lot of disk IO for example, your load will go higher because more processes are waiting their turn. Whereas when your processes are performing operations on a faster medium (RAM) the IO should be much lower and therefore the load should be lower.

When something like a database starts up it is often loading a lot of data from the disks and thus generating higher than normal load averages.

Answer (score 0):

Also, since you have CSF you also have a process that gets started by CSF @ boot. The md5sum process checks the hashes of files causing a high iowait thus increasing the load of your server.